# Difference in times is returning a negative number

Tags: ruby, time

I have this trial timer code to time euler solutions in Ruby.

```
$RUNS = 12
def run(solve)
  times = []
  $RUNS.times do
    start_t = Time.now.usec
    solve.call
    end_t = Time.now.usec
    times << (end_t - start_t)/1000.0
  end
  #times = times.delete_if {|i| i < 0}
  puts times.inspect
  times.sort

  mean = times.inject{|a,c| a+c} / $RUNS
  puts("Mean:\t#{mean}");
  if (times.length % 2 == 0) then
    median = (times[times.length / 2 - 1] + times[times.length / 2]) / 2.0
  else 
    median = times[times.length / 2];
  end
  puts("Median: #{median}");

end
```

Unfortunately, I keep getting answers like this:

```
[409.805, 418.16, -582.23, 402.223, -581.94, 413.196, 426.816, -584.732, 519.457, -569.557, 558.918, -579.176]
```

What can I do to avoid these strange negative numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`usec` returns the microseconds from the time in the same was as `month` returns the month. It is not the number of microseconds for the given time since the epoch.

So if `start_t` was 1049896564.259970 seconds and `end_t` was 1049896592.123130 seconds then you would get 123130 - 259970 if you subtracted the usecs. i.e. a negative number.

Instead you could use `Time.now.to_f` to convert to floating point number of seconds since epoch and subtract those from each other. You can also just subtract one `Time` object from another directly e.g.

```
start_t = Time.now
solve.call
end_t = Time.now
times << end_t - start_t
```

Comment: Then how do I do high-granularity timing in ruby?

Comment: @JBristow Answer updated with a suggestion of how to do what you want.

Comment: It seems like this is asking for floating point errors, but I am multiplying by 1000 to get msec granularity.

Comment: You should also take a look at [benchmark](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/index.html) in the standard library, although if you look at the source for that I think it still just uses `to_f` when calculating time deltas.

Answer (score 0):

Current time in seconds since the Epoch:

```
Time.now.to_f
=> 1278631398.143
```

That should have microsecond resolution, despite only three decimal places being shown here.